# Не меняется изображение по onClick из другого Activity

Tags: android, изображения, activity

Если я меняю изображение по кнопке из MainActivity, то изображение меняется.

Если я создаю новый Activity и унаследую все из MainActivity, то изображение не меняется, а приложение крошится.

```
    image_1 = findViewById(R.id.image);
    image_1.setImageResource(R.drawable.cat);
```

Лог ошибки:

> Process: com.example.game, PID: 9320
>               java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
>                   at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:402)
>                   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256)
>                   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701)
>                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
>                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
>                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
>                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                   at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
>                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
>                Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                   at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:397)
>                   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256) 
>                   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701) 
>                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789) 
>                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 
>                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
>                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                   at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
>                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767) 
>                Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(int)' on a null object reference
>                   at com.example.topper.Shar_Activity.click_shar_1(Shar_Activity.java:33)
>                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                   at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:397) 
>                   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256) 
>                   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701) 
>                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789) 
>                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 
>                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
>                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                   at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
>                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)

Разметка второго Активити:

```
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;


public class Shar_Activity extends MainActivity {

    private ImageView image_shar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_shar);
        image_shar = findViewById(R.id.shar);

    }

    public void click_shar_1(View view) {


        image_shar.setImageResource(R.drawable.shar_1);


    }


    public void click_shar_2(View view) {


        image_shar.setImageResource(R.drawable.shar_2);

    }

    public void click_shar_3(View view) {

        image_shar.setImageResource(R.drawable.shar_3);
    }
}
```

Comment: покажите лог ошибки

Comment: ошибка говорит о том что `imageView` не инициализирована

Comment: Покажите разметку, используемую во второй активити.